# Registering and Installing bower packages from GitLab

Tags: bower, gitlab, bower-install, bower-register

We have created a private repository in GitLab and we wanted to host our bower packages in there so that when user types `bower install myprivatepackage` it should pull the package form GitLab.
This is the command I am typing to register the bower package, but it throws an `Unknown Error 503`:
`bower register myprivatepackage git://gitlab.com/<user_name>/<my_repo>.git`.
What step did I miss?

**EDIT**: Seems like `git://` is only for public repositories and not for private ones. Private repos can be accessed through `https://` or 'ssh`. Link here: https://github.com/bower/registry/issues/4